# Build failure при создании maven-archetype-webapp

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, build

Пытаюсь в intellij idea создать модуль maven с архитипом для web приложения java. При создании падает ошибка, хотя если создавать обычный модуль maven без архитипа то все нормально

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.106 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-01T18:37:03+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:RELEASE or one of its dependencies
 could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:RELEASE: Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:RELEASE:
 Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Artem\.m2\repository) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>homework_13</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-archetype-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно решить эту проблему? Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Приложите ваш `pom.xml`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov сделал.  В homework_13, кроме пома больше ничего нет, если что. Обновил

Comment: Вы ипорт pom в идее сделали? У вас просто не скачался пакет

Comment: @Anton импорт pom,а как это? я просто добавил зависимость, шла долгая загрузка, но в конце концов она завершилась, хотя справа она также горит красным - unresolved, несмотря на то что я сделал Invalidate cache/Restart. А еще, у меня теперь появилось куча новых архитипов при создании модуля maven

Comment: На вкладке Maven нажмите две первых кнопки: стрелки и папку